# Python SQL how to look for non-matches in other tables?

Tags: python, sql, mariadb

I'm looking for a solution so that I can check for non-matches in other tables.

Basically I have 3 tables (see below). Here I want to look into Table 1, and identify the first row that doesn't have a match in either Name or Location. If both is recognized it should move to next row and check.

I have tried to accomplish this with SQL and looping through them, but as I only want the first row that doesn't match I haven't found a smooth solution (or pretty for that sake, as I'm fairly rookie-ish).

I'm pretty sure this can be accomplished with SQL.

Table 1

```
Id   Name  Location
1    John  Canada
2    James Brazil
3    Jim   Hungary
```

Table 2 - Recognized Names

```
Id   Name
1    John
2    James
```

Table 3 - Recognized Locations

```
Id   Location
1    Brazil
2    Hungary
```

So I want to select from Table 1, where Name can't find a match in Table 2 or where Location can't find a match in Table 3.

In my example from above the result should be Id = 1, as Location is not in Table 3.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first row... as ordered by Id? Terms as 'first' don't really mean much unless you specify in your SQL some ordering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `not exists` to select if some sub-query doesn't select a row:

```
select
  *
from
  Table1 t1
where
  not exists (
    select * from Table2 t2 where t2.`Name` = t1.`Name`
  ) and
  not exists (
    select * from Table3 t3 where t3.`Location` = t1.`Location`
  )
order by
  t1.Id
limit 1
```

It's not a very complicated query, but still some things are going on, so here is the same one again, but with comments to explain the various parts:

```
select
  /* I select all columns, *, for the example, but in real life scenarios 
     it's always better to explicitly specify which columns you need. */
  *
from
  /* Optionally, you can specify a short or different alias for a table (t1)
     this can be helpful to make your query more readable by allowing you to explicitly
     specify where a column is coming from, without cluttering the query with long names. */
  Table1 t1
where
  /* exists takes a sub-query, which is executed for each row of the main query.
     The expression returns true if the subquery returns a row. 
     With not (not exists), the expression is inversed: true becomes false. */
  not exists (
    /* In MariaDB, backticks can be used to escape identifiers that also are 
       reserved words. You are allowed to use them for any identifier, but
      for reserved word identifiers, they are often necessary. */
    select * from Table2 t2 where t2.`Name` = t1.`Name`
  )
  /* Combine the two subqueries. We only want rows don't have a matching row 
     in sub-query one, and neither in sub-query two. */
  and
  not exists (
    select * from Table3 t3 where t3.`Location` = t1.`Location`
  )
/* Specify _some_ ordering by which you can distinguish 'first' from 'second'. */
order by
  t1.Id
/* Return only 1 row (the first according to the order clause) */
limit 1
```

Comment: This is excellent! Thank you. One comment; I changed "and not exists" to "or not exists" as I got 0 results.

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted the `no match in either` in your question as `not in both`. It should indeed be `or` then.